# how to install Mediapipe when calling Python script with Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit, mediapipe

I am trying to call a python script using [Streamlit](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit). I have a `requirements.txt` file that installs the libraries used in the script:

```
...
mediapipe==0.8.10.1
...
```

All the libraries successfully download but the [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) library does not install no matter what I do and gives me this error:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.8.10.1
```

Please help with the installation of the Mediapipe. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zainab. Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the version of Python you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well. I fixed by using a VPN(Try https://1.1.1.1).

Ironically that package was getting blocked by my ISP.